# Outlook Shows Contacting Dialog When Viewing Email

Tags: image, html-email, outlook-2010

Outlook keeps showing the following images when trying to display images from our image server.

Here is an example of the image its trying to load.

http://ihfiles.com/products/5736_1_0_300_100_0.jpg

[image]

Any thoughts on what might be causing outlook to contact our image server in an extremely slow manner?

Answer (score 1):

Discovered the issue.  Images embeded in the email were missing "http:" so mail services like gmail could discover the image but not mail clients like Outlook or iPhone Mail App.

So URLs were
//ihfiles.com/products/16184_2_0_100_100_0.jpg

Not
http://ihfiles.com/products/16184_2_0_100_100_0.jpg